# Reading a nested list in a CSV column with Cassava

Tags: csv, haskell

An example is easier to explain so I would like to parse this data into a datatype with cassava

```
title;authors
Cambridge Economic History;Ian MorrisWalter,ScheidelRichard,P Saller
```

I tried to do the following but it does not work (minimal not-working example) :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}

module Library where

import Data.Csv
import Data.List.Split
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text as T
import GHC.Generics

data Book = Book {
  title :: T.Text,
  authors :: Authors
} deriving (Generic, Show)

type Authors = [T.Text]

instance FromNamedRecord Book

instance FromNamedRecord Authors
parseField "authors" =
    pure $ splitOn "," ???
    
opts = defaultDecodeOptions {
  decDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord ';')
  }

main c = do
  csvData <- BL.readFile "data.csv"
  let res = decodeByNameWith opts csvData :: Either String (Header, V.Vector Book)
```

Is it possible to do it in Cassava ? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write a customized `FromNamedRecord` instance for `Book`, instead of deriving the `Generic` one.  It would look something like:

```
instance FromNamedRecord Book where
  parseNamedRecord m = Book <$>
    m .: "title" <*>
    (T.splitOn "," <$> m .: "authors")
```

Here, `m .: "authors"` retrieves the authors field as a `Text` record, and the `T.splitOn ","` is fmapped (`<$>`) over that result to split the `Text` into `[Text]` by commas.

The full program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Library where

import Data.Char
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

data Book = Book {
  title :: T.Text,
  authors :: Authors
} deriving (Show)

type Authors = [T.Text]

instance FromNamedRecord Book where
  parseNamedRecord m = Book <$>
    m .: "title" <*>
    (T.splitOn "," <$> m .: "authors")

opts = defaultDecodeOptions {
  decDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord ';')
  }

main = do
  csvData <- BL.readFile "data.csv"
  let res = decodeByNameWith opts csvData :: Either String (Header, V.Vector Book)
  print res
```

giving:

```
λ> main
Right (["title","authors"],[Book {title = "Cambridge Economic History",
authors = ["Ian MorrisWalter","ScheidelRichard","P Saller"]}])
```

Note that this doesn't allow you to handle per-author quoting in the author list, so if you need to parse an author with an embedded comma, like:

```
Another Book;John Smith,"Anne Douglas, Jr."
```

you'll be out of luck.  Cassava will refuse to parse an "authors" field with embedded quotes like this, and you'll end up having to write your own specialized CSV parser, I think.

Comment: Awesome ! I would never have found the syntax from the custom `FromNamedRecord` by myself.